# Wordpress: how to open older entries in a different template?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create a custom wordpress theme, but since I'm kinda inexperienced at it, I ran into a problem.

Here is what the index page layout is like:
At the top of the page I'm displaying single featured post, which can be any post with a category "featured" checked.

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=1' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<div class="featuredpost">
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
?>
<ul class="featuredpostcontent">
    <li><h1><a class="excerptheader" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></li>
    <li><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"?>Read more</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Below that I'm displaying 6 latest posts, excluding the one that is set to be featured.

```
    <?php
    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts('showposts=6&category_id=-3'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<ul class="latestposts">
    <li><h3><a class="excerptheader" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
        <ul>
            <li><?php the_excerpt(); ?></li>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"?>Read more</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

at the bottom of the page there is a pagination

```
<div class="next-posts"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries') ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts"><?php previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;') ?></div>
```

Right now when I click on older entries link they open within the same page layout. I would like them to open within a different layout, one that would display only 6 older or newer posts and would not have the featured post at the top.
How would I pull this out?

Comment: On a sidenote, 90% of cases you can use `wp_reset_postdata()` which will normalize your query. `wp_reset_query()` is too much (though on a small website you won't notice the difference). [Read More!](http://www.poststat.us/properly-reset-wordpress-query/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the featured post conditional via query string?

turn your pagination into:

```
<div class="next-posts"><?php echo get_next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries').'?hide_featured_post=true'; ?></div>
<div class="prev-posts"><?php echo get_previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;').'hide_featured_post=true'; ?></div>
```

and your template to:

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=1' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
if($_GET['hide_featured_post'] == true){
?>
<div class="featuredpost">
<?php 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } 
?>
<ul class="featuredpostcontent">
    <li><h1><a class="excerptheader" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></li>
    <li><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </li>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"?>Read more</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<?php 
}
endwhile; 
?>
```

If the next or previews post links actually include a query string (unsure if they do or not), then you can just use those in place of the $_GET variable I used.

Comment: This hides the featured post on index page by default.